# terraform 11 and "concat" function: parse error

Tags: terraform, terraform0.11

TF v.0.11 (I know it is old but I need this one)

I try to configure output this way:

```
value = "${concat(aws_lambda_function.lambda.*.arn, [""])}"
```

The error message is

> Error reading config for output FUNCTION_ARN: parse error at 1:46 :
> expected expression but found "["

What am I doing wrong, how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason: `[""]` don't work for v11.

Solution:

```
value = "${element(concat(aws_lambda_function.lambda.*.arn, list("")), 0)}"
```

Comment: Using legacy v11 scripts. It's pain.